# How to override express routes

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Every time that i try to use the first route, i get the second one instead.

There is any way to override the second route when i get a '/allAnswered' request?

```
router.get('/allAnswered', verify.verifyAdmin, async (req, res) => {
  await reportService.getAllAnswered(req.query.userId, req.query.sessionId, (response) => {
    res.status(response.status).send(response);
  })
});

router.get('/:reportId', verify.verifyAdmin, async (req, res) => {
  await reportService.getReportById(req.params.reportId, (response) => {
    res.status(response.status).send(response);
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
You should write something like this:

```
router.get('/reports/:reportId,verify.verifyAdmin, async (req, res) => {
  await reportService.getReportById(req.params.reportId, (response) => {
    res.status(response.status).send(response);
  })
});
```

Comment: These routes already have the '/reports' prefix implicitly, this code is from the reports controller

Answer (score 0):

don't think express allow this, you can consider using this style:

```
router.get('/:reportId', verify.verifyAdmin, async (req, res) => {
  if (req.params.reportId === 'allAnswered') {
    await reportService.getAllAnswered(req.query.userId, req.query.sessionId, 
    (response) => {
     res.status(response.status).send(response);
    })
  } else {
    await reportService.getReportById(req.params.reportId, (response) => {
      res.status(response.status).send(response);
    })
  }

});
```